# PHP Extension gd disabled

Tags: 7, installation, files

I know this question is floating out there in the forums, but so far all of the answers I've come across over the weekend have been unable to resolve this issue.

I'm working on an Amazon LAMP server (Non-Ubuntu) and have been trying to enable the GD extension so that I may install Drupal 7 on my new AWS site.

The page installation process is producing the following error:

- [X] PHP extensions Disabled: Drupal requires you to enable the PHP extensions in the following list (see the system requirements page for more information): gd

Here's what I know from my PHPInfo page: http://ec2-54-173-231-195.compute-1.amazonaws.com/info.php

I've gone ahead and run my scripts to install the gd script which I'm produced with the following result:

- Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
- amzn-main/latest|2.1 kB 00:00
- amzn-updates/latest | 2.3 kB 00:00
- No package php5-gd available
- Error: Nothing to do

I have also restarted my httpd and mysqld in efforts to restart the system and have my machine honor any restart needed to launch my extension recognition.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was actually due to I was running php 5.5.*. The following code resolved my issue for any who come across it themselves.

To discover if you too are running over that version type the following:

```
php -v
```

Once you've determined your running PHP 5.5.* type the following:

```
sudo yum install php55-gd

sudo service httpd restart
sudo service mysqld restart
```

That should resolve your issue.